# Wifi on Fedora trouble

Tags: fedora, wifi, wpa-supplicant

My university's WiFi is particularly unfriendly to Linux, and the only way to make WiFi work is to repeatedly "forget" the network settings for the student network, re-enter all the data about the network, and hope it will connect. I am using Fedora 19 64-bit on my laptop, but this is not the only distro that has WiFi connectivity problems. Android devices are generally incapable of WiFi access, and when I ran Ubuntu, CentOS, and Mint, they all had similar problems.

My question is, how would I go about creating a script that would automate the "forget network, re-enter network info" hack that I've been using to get WiFi?

As a side note, I am open to more investigative, less hackish solutions that might require more looking at system logs. I am no stranger to bash but logs and more hands on diagnostics are a bit of a mystery to me.

Also, my WiFi works fine on my home network, and every other network I've used it with except my university WiFi.

Additional info edit: using wpa_supplicant

My university runs WPA2-enterprise with AES, and PEAP using MSCHAPv2

Comment: What application are you using to connect to the network? NetworkManager? I have successfully used both `wicd` and a handwritten `wpa_supplicant` configuration in this kind of networks (PEAP w/ MSCHAPv2).

Comment: I am using wpa_supplicant.

Comment: In that case it's not really clear to me what do you mean b y *"forget network, re-enter network info"*. Nevertheless, sharing your `wpa_supplicant.conf` might be a good start - remember to edit out any passwords (and usernames).

Comment: I use Cinnamon, it has a network applet in the task bar, where you can select forget network if there is information stored about a particular network, and then it offers a prompt to connect to the "newly discovered network" that it was just told to forget where all new info can be entered. going through this process usually results in a connection after 1 or 2 tries.

Comment: That sounds more like NetworkManager than `wpa_supplicant` - which is almost certainly running in the background but you are **not running it by hand** in a terminal (or similarly). And that exactly would be the first thing to try: putting together a `wpa_supplicant.conf` (NM is storing these somewhere for each network you connect to) and running `wpa_supplicant` directly, preferably so that it doesn't fork into background, e.g.: `wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i wlan1 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -d`.

Comment: Such kind of WiFi trouble in my experience is due to driver instabilities and/or bad (or *very* bad) signal. Particularly Android devices have small/insensitive antennas. What WiFi card do you have? Latest distribution version, kernel?